# Provide ip address from local machine

Tags: tcp

I am developing an application that will accept TCP/IP connections and depending on the IP address I need to do different things.
I understand that I can get the ip address when a client connects but I am wondering how I can test this on a local pc.
I can have another application connecting but I can only use the loopback 127.0.0.0.
So I need a program that runs on my pc that can connect to my application with different ip addresses.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: So what do you need exactly? Your code? Or new ip address on your local machine?

Comment: `[c#]` != `[c++]`

Comment: Remember that 127.0.0.1 isn't your only loopback IP address. 127.0.0.1/8 is loopback (so all IPs from 127.0.0.1 to 127.255.255.254 are loopback).

Answer (score 1):

Spinning up one or more virtual machines and connecting them through a virtual switch is an easy way of testing out networked applications. You can also use a virtual loopback interface without using VMs, but it's trickier to ensure that the networking is actually doing what you expect it to do.